# How to measure the altitude of an object in the sky?

Tags: measurements, telescopes

If I use a telescope to observe a plane in the sky, how can I find the altitude of the plane(altitude of the plane with respect to the ground)?

Comment: Do you know anything else, like the dimensions of the plane?

Comment: I don't know. You can assume it as unknown variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the dimensions of the plane then it is possible to calculate its distance. One way of doing that is with a [stadiametirc rangefinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadiametric_rangefinding). If the airplane dimensions are unknown, you can also find the distance by using two telescopes and calculating the distance by [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation). After you have established the distance, you can calculate the altitude by taking the cosine of the angle the telescope made with the ground and multiplying by the distance.